# How to install c++ build tools in a conda virtual environment for use with cython/setproctitle

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, anaconda, cython

I'm attempting to run a deep learning model found here: https://github.com/chenyilun95, however it has parts that are cythonized. I have yet to work with cython and attempted to install the requisites in a conda virtual environment, however upon attempting to pip install setproctitle, I get the following error:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

Nothing else has any issues and I'm yet to find how to install c++ build tools onto a conda environment, so some assistance here would be helpful as either there's not a lot of info on it or my googling skills are lacking.

If it's relevant, some versions:

```
pip==10.0.1
Cython==0.28.2
setuptools==39.1.0
numpy>=1.7.1
scipy>=0.13.2
```

It's also worth noting the link that it gives me to find the build tools is broken. I'm aware I can find the build tools on my own, it's just a note.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem recently trying to run Pybullet on Windows. I found the standalone .exe for Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 at this link: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&fixForIE=.exe